# react-scrollmagic 'setPin()': Invalid pin element supplied. error

Tags: reactjs, gsap, scrollmagic, react-scrollmagic

I'm using `react-scrollmagic` together with `react-gasp` and getting an error in the console: `(ScrollMagic.Scene) -> ERROR calling method 'setPin()': Invalid pin element supplied.` .

Everything seems to be working fine on the front end though, but in a more complex project these console errors add up very quickly. I can't get rid of the error no matter what I try. Is there any solution to this?

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Controller, Scene } from "react-scrollmagic";
import { Timeline, Tween } from "react-gsap";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Controller>
        <Scene duration={500} triggerElement={"h1"} pin>
          {(progress) => (
            <Timeline
              totalProgress={progress}
              target={<h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>}
            >
              <Tween from={{ opacity: "0" }} to={{ opacity: "1" }} />
            </Timeline>
          )}
        </Scene>
      </Controller>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the code and error in action at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-payne-jyx7j?file=/src/App.js:0-638).

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use the ScrollTrigger component instead of "react-scrollmagic". It's a modern version of ScrollMagic and plays better together with the Timeline or Tween components.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Timeline, Tween, ScrollTrigger } from "react-gsap";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ScrollTrigger start="top center" end="500px center" pin markers>
        <Timeline target={<h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>}>
          <Tween from={{ opacity: "0" }} to={{ opacity: "1" }} />
        </Timeline>
      </ScrollTrigger>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Have a look at the react-gsap docs and official gsap docs:

https://bitworking.github.io/react-gsap/src-components-scroll-trigger
https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger